# Installing Nuget packages using Yarn without using Bower or npm

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget

So I am seeing a lot of questions regarding .NET Core 2.1 and installing NuGet packages, but nobody has really recently addressed it clearly or (from what I've seen regarding my own configuration) correctly.

I'm trying to figure out how to install packages like jQueryUI or some other third-party packages from GitHub without using Bower (which is being deprecated), Webpack (which is entirely too bloated), or npm (which is far too confusing and doesn't actually get the packages installed where I need them, which is wwwroot/lib).

I am using Yarn as a client-side deployment tool, but Yarn isn't installing jQueryUI correctly. .NET Core is very, VERY new, and I think a lot of answers on SOF are taking some steps for granted.

Can someone please provide a clear path forward on how to install, say, jQueryUI and Bootstrap into a new .NET Core MVC Web Application (not the empty one)?

Comment: Even though some packages are maintained, you **should not** depend on NuGet for client-side libraries like jQuery or bootstrap. NPM is the easy, already built-in way to go